# For Every Measure Zero Set $E$ There Exists a Positive Measure with Lower Lebesgue Density 0 and Upper Lebesgue Density 1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is related to a question asked on mathstackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831184/for-every-null-set-e-there-is-a-measurable-set-f-with-different-upper-and-lo. This question is inspired by Remark 7.4 from the paper $\textit{Structure of Null Sets in the Plane and Applications}$.

The remark in the paper states that given a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ of measure zero one can find a set $F\subset \mathbb{R}$ of positive measure so that all the points of $E$ have lower Lebesgue density 0 and upper Lebesgue density 1.

In the mathstackexchange post, the answer uses the uncentred balls definition for upper and lower Lebesgue density (i.e. the lower Lebesgue density is defined as $$\liminf_{x\in B,m(B)\rightarrow 0} \frac{m(F\cap B)}{m(B)}$$ and the upper Lebesgue density is defined in the same way with $\limsup$ instead of $\liminf$). My question is, is it possible to find a set $F$ using the centred balls definition of Lebesgue density? That is, given a set of $E$ of measure 0 can we find a set $F$ of positive measure so that $$\liminf_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{m(F\cap B_r(x))}{m(B_r(x))} = 0$$ and $$\limsup_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{m(F\cap B_r(x))}{m(B_r(x))} = 1$$ for all $x\in E$?

Comment: You want $E, F\subset\mathbb R$, as in the linked question?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Ahhh! Thank you. That is very important. Yes, $E,F \subset \mathbb{R}$. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can do this by a small modification of the original argument, see the [linked question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831184/for-every-null-set-e-there-is-a-measurable-set-f-with-different-upper-and-lo) I'll describe the whole argument again here, but if you already read those answers, then the short version is that we remove successively less of each $I_n(p)$ as we approach the boundary of that interval. This allows us (for each $x\in I_n(p)$) to replace $I_n(p)$ by its maximal subinterval centered at $x$ while only slightly disturbing the approximate densities.

Construct open sets $G_1\supset G_2 \supset \ldots \supset E$, as follows. Start with any open $G_1\supset E$, and write $G_1 = \bigcup I_1(p)$ as the union of its components. For each $I_1(p)$, we construct an open set $G_2(p)$ with $E\subset G_2(p)\subset I_1(p)$. This $G_2(p)$ will cover only a small portion of $I_1(p)$ (possible since $|E|=0$), and, moreover, this portion will not be unduly concentrated near the boundary of $I_1(p)$ (this is the modification). More specifically, if $I_1(p)=(a,b)$, then we demand that
$$
|(a,a+h)\cap G_2(p)| \le 2^{-1}h \quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
for all $h>0$, and similarly near $b$. We can do this by cutting $I_1(p)$ into pieces $(a+2^{-k}, a+2^{-k+1})$ and treating these separately (if an endpoint is in $E$ here, I very slightly move such a point).

Then we put $G_2=\bigcup G_2(p)=\bigcup I_2(q)$. We repeat this whole procedure, with $2^{-1}$ replaced by $2^{-2}$ in (1), to obtain $G_3$ etc., and we finally set $F=\bigcup (G_{2n-1}\setminus G_{2n})$ (start with $G_1$, remove $G_2$, add $G_3$ etc. etc.).

If $x\in E$, then $x\in I_n(p_n)$ for some (unique) $p_n$ for all $n$. If $n$ is odd and we write $I_n(p_n)=(a,b)$ and $x$ is closer to $a$ than to $b$, then we consider $J=(a,a+2(x-a))$. Then $J\cap F\supset J\setminus G_{n+1}$, so (1) says that $|J\cap F|/|J|$ is almost $1$ if $n$ is large.

Similarly, we find intervals for which this ratio is almost zero from the even $n$'s.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I guess the wiggle room that you take advantage of is that we used the measure to find the sets $G_i$, but this is done in some black box sort of way and we don't really know anything about them. Your idea is to still let the measure pick the sets $G_i$, but you only let it pick sets from the universe of sets satisfying condition (1). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and I can do this by cutting $I$ into smaller pieces. Say $I$ is $[0,1]$. Then, for each large $k$, I choose an open set $H_k$ with $E\subset H_k \subset (2^{-k},2^{-k+1})$ with $|H_k|\le 2^{-n-k}$ (if we are at step $n$). This just uses (outer) regularity of Lebesgue measure. Then $G_{n+1}(p)$ is the union of these $H_k$'s.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for your answer!